# Android progressDialog dont't show if startActivity(myIntent)

Tags: android, show, progressdialog

I am using this simple code

```
public class Main extends Activity {
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  //bouton Exemples de prix
    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //start the progress dialog
                    runDialog(4);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Exemple_prix.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);

                }
            }
    );  

}

private void runDialog(final int seconds)
{
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Chargement...");

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

The `progressDialog` doesn't show but it works if I disable

```
//startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your progress dialog is tied to the activity, so it shows on top of the first activity, then immediately you're starting the new activity which covers both the old activity and the progress dialog. Is there a particular reason why you're showing the progress dialog? If it's related to work in the second activity, you should show it there instead.

On a side note, don't create a new thread just to sleep like that. Just use [`postDelayed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29).

Comment: Finaly, this code works normaly with 2.2 emulator problem is with 1.5